# Where do I save output feature classes from web tools in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I have a model that creates several temporary layers and then one final output layer. When I run it in ModelBuilder, I specify the output path each time depending on the project I'm working in since I use this model in a variety of different projects/with different input data.

I understand that there is less control over output locations with web tools, but I am wondering where the output feature class can be saved so I can access it immediately after running the tool?

I played around with %scratchGDB% but from what I understand, the web tool will always use the same scratch workspace that was specified in the Environments section of the model execution that the web tool was published from. Where do web tools with outputs usually save those output layers?